# Must declare scalar variable error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to display sql select results from code-behind and however this error occurred:

> *Must declare the scalar variable "@poNum".*
>
> Line 75:  sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("@poNum", poNum.Text.Trim());
>   Line 76:
>   Line 77: DataView dvMember = (DataView)sdsUsers.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty); //here the error
>   Line 78: DataTable tblMember = dvMember.Table;

Code:

```
string connectionString2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WholesaleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string selectSql = "SELECT invoiceNum, poNum FROM SendInvoice where poNum = @poNum";

SqlDataSource sdsUsers = new SqlDataSource(connectionString2, selectSql); 
sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Clear(); 
sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("@poNum", poNum.Text.Trim());

DataView dvMember = (DataView)sdsUsers.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty); //error occured here 
DataTable tblMember = dvMember.Table;

for(int i=0;i<tblMember.Rows.Count;i++) { 
            if (i==0){ 
             Label aaa = new Label();
             aaa.Text = tblMember.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            } 
        }
```

I am stuck with this problems for days and I couldn't find a solution

Comment: Consider using the ADO.NET [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) class instead of the ASP.NET `SqlDataSource` control for basic data retrieval.

Comment: Please try changing this `sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("@poNum", poNum.Text.Trim());` to this `sdsUsers.SelectParameters.AddWithValue("@poNum", poNum.Text.Trim());`

Comment: I also had the at @ symbol in both the SQL Select statement AND the SelectParameters.Add(). It only needs to be in the later.

Answer (score 2):

I would try removing the @ from the paramater name (leave it in your SQL though):

```
sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("poNum", poNum.Text.Trim());
```

or (assuming poNum is an int):

```
sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("poNum", System.TypeCode.Int32, poNum));
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Clear();
```

should come after

```
sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("@poNum", poNum.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: And you mean `Clear()` should be right after `Add()`? That makes no sense.